# Synchronizing multiple observable streams

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I am quite new to work with Reactive Extensions, so this might be a newbie question, but i have the following scenario:

I fetch 3 IEnumerable lists (of different types) from the database and populate a view model. I would however like to coordinate the subscriptions to trigger something when all lists have completed loading. Is this possible with Reactive Extensions or am i thinking in the wrong way? Code loks like this:

```
GetCustomers()
    .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
    .Buffer(20).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Subscribe(View.Model.AddRange);
GetCountries()
    .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
    .Buffer(20).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Subscribe(View.Model.AddRange);
GetTransports()
    .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
    .Buffer(20).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Subscribe(View.Model.AddRange);
```

Comment: Does each `IEnumerable<T>` work on a different `T`?

Comment: Yes, they all have different types. Also View.Model.AddRange have overloads for the three different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using observable joins. Something like this:

```
var plan =
    Observable.Start(() => GetCountries())
        .And(Observable.Start(() => GetCustomers()))
        .And(Observable.Start(() => GetTransports()))
        .Then((countries, customers, transports)
            => new { countries, customers, transports });

var query =
    Observable.When(new [] { plan });

query
    .Subscribe(cct =>
    {
        View.Model.AddRange(cct.countries);
        View.Model.AddRange(cct.customers);
        View.Model.AddRange(cct.transports);
    });
```

It runs in parallel and you get all the results in one at the end.

Comment: I think OP wanted the lists to load in parallel, but know when they all completed.

Comment: Yes @Asti, this loads the lists in parallel, but only displays them when they all are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd change an already synchronous Enumerable into an Observable, but in Rx idioms, you could:

```
Observable.Merge(Add(GetCustomers()), Add(GetCountries())..., Add(GetTransports()))
           .Subscribe(() => { }, Completed);
```

where Add could be:

```
    private IObservable<Unit> Add<T>(IObservable<T> o)
    {
        return o.Buffer(20)
                .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                .Do(View.Model.AddRange)
                .Select(_ => Unit.Default);
    }
```

Comment: How will this work since `T` is different for all three observables?

Comment: @casperOne  I don't know what his internal logic is, but OP calls `View.Model.AddRange` for all 3. In case of different types, they can be narrowed down by `Get()...Do(action).Select(_ => new Unit())`.

Comment: Based on the clarification, this won't work, as `T` is different for all the observables (there are overloads for `AddRange`).

Comment: @casperOne I did mention an alternate solution in the comment above. I've added edited the answer to reflect that.